# Why does NSTimer persist firing while app is suspended?

Tags: ios, nstimer

As far i know, there are two distinct stages of iOS application lifecycle when it is hidden:

- **Background** - when we are still able to proceed computation and run code;
- **Suspended** - when any computation is freezed and we can't do anything till the user returns to the app.

So i'm a bit confused about a following example:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    (void)(^expirationHandler)() = [^{
        [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
        self.bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    } copy];   
    self.bgTask = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithName:@"MyTask" expirationHandler:expirationHandler];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(count)
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:YES];
    expirationHandler();
}

- (void)count {
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 10000000) {
         i++;
    }
    NSLog(@"%d", i);
}
```

*P.S. I've reproduced it from memory, let me know if something wrong, but question is not related to correctness of the snippet.*

I tested it on iPhone 6+ with iOS 9.3 and the specified timer persists firing, furthermore count method executes code (you can check it by `i` value). Am i right that app must proceed to suspended state after the timer scheduled? If so, why is `count` able to execute code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show us the declaration of `bgTask`? Is it an instance variable? I'm trying to rule out that what you capture in the block is a value, not a reference.

Comment: It is ivar in the sample, but i think you will get the same result even with local `__block` variable

Comment: Are you testing while running under the debugger in Xcode?  If so, then you app doesn't have background time limits or get suspended

Comment: @Paulw11, yes i am. It makes sense. Is there any mentions from official docs about such behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [@Paulw11](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3418066/paulw11) in comments,

> Are you testing while running under the debugger in Xcode? If so, then you app doesn't have background time limits or get suspended

I haven't found any proofs, but through empirical enquiry it appears to be true.